# Simple way to add static content to footer

Tags: magento2, footer, luma-theme

[image]

In which file can I just add HTML to add content to the footer, only using the luma theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide below is based on you not having any cms block yet for this.

1. Go to Content -> Blocks
2. Create a new block (button: Add New Block)

   - Enable: Yes
   - Block Title: Footer Links Block
   - Identifier: footer_links_block
   - Store view: whatever is appropriate for your installation
   - Content: just put some content here
3. Save
4. Go to Content -> Widgets
5. Create a new widget (button: Add Widget)

   - Type: CMS Static Block
   - Design Theme: Your theme
6. Click Continue
7. Configure Storefront Properties

   - Widget Title: Footer Links
   - Assign to Store Views: whatever is appropriate for your installation
8. Click Add Layout Update
9. Display on: All Pages
10. Container: CMS Footer Links
11. Click on the Widget Options tab
12. Click on the button Select Block
13. Select your block: Footer Links Block
14. Click on Save (top right orange button)
15. Refresh caches

Reload your frontend. You should now see the content of your Footer Links Block.

Answer (score 1):

Your theme may support blocks, check the documentation.

Alternatively, you can add customer HTML to your footer here:

**System** > **Configuration** > **General** > **Design** > **Footer**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the backend:

> Content -> Block -> Footer Links Block

Comment: Don't have any blocks in the backend